# Handling the IE ActiveX Popup window using Watir

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, activex, watir

Is there any way to programmatically click on the Yes button in the IE ActiveX Popup window using Watir.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Tutorial), this is not possible:

> Watir will drive web applications that are served up as HTML pages in a web browser. Watir will not work with ActiveX plugin components, Java Applets, Macromedia Flash, or other plugin applications. To determine whether Watir can be used to automate a part of a web application, right click on the object and see if the View Source menu option is available. If you can view the HTML source, that object can be automated using Watir